# Optimal way to control PWM with ADC on AVR controller

Tags: assembly, avr, pwm, adc

I get 8-bit value from `ADC` (it lies in [0, 1024) ) but I need to convert them to duty cycle in timer `PWM` mode (it lies in [25, 255]). What's the most optimal way to do this using assembly?

Comment: The range [0,1024) won't fit in 8 bits, it requires 10 - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

- divide ADC value by 4, meaning to read in the ADC value into a
  register and then shift it 2 times to the right
- then make sure that
  you set it to 25 if the shifted result is < 25

**EDIT**

if you want a non-linear response to your ADC reading you can create a <s>256</s> **1024 byte** table ... potentially starting with 25x "25" and then any function stepping up towards 255, and use the **un**shifted ADC value as an index into this table ... this is how for instance logarithmic LED dimming curves are programmed.

Comment: For a non-linear conversion table you might want to have 1024 entries rather than shifting the index.